# How to get entropy from JVM?

Tags: java, random, cryptography, jvm, secure-random

Let's say I need good seed to initialize pseudo random generator (PRNG) in Java program and I don't have access to any hardware random generator.

How to get entropy from JVM without any user interaction?

Comment: How about using a SecureRandom directly, instead?

Comment: I suggest you use a SecureRandom. Some of the modes use entropy to generate the seed.

Comment: I'd like to write custom PRNG. SecureRandom is not so secure. It uses SHA1PRNG by default in Windows (Java 8). SHA-1 is going to be depreciated http://www.pcworld.com/article/3173791/security/stop-using-sha1-it-s-now-completely-unsafe.html.

Comment: You can use SecureRandom to source your entropy.

Comment: For reference https://tersesystems.com/2015/12/17/the-right-way-to-use-securerandom/

Comment: And http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/random_numbers/entropy_sources.shtml

Comment: Do you mean that you cannot rely on `/dev/random` or `/dev/urandom`?

Comment: And instead of deleting [your previous, nearly identical question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42452420/how-to-get-entropy-from-jvm) you should simply have improved it so it could be reopened. It means duplicate effort for everyone else.

Answer (score 3):

> SHA-1 is going to be depreciated

The vulnerability is not relevant to CSPRNG construction.

> How to get entropy from JVM?

`SecureRandom` is a generic facade over various security providers, [including OS-specific entropy sources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/StandardNames.html#SecureRandom)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`generateSeed(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/SecureRandom.html#generateSeed(int)) or [`getSeed(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/SecureRandom.html#getSeed(int)) to statically retrieve the seed input that is also used for `SecureRandom` itself. Then you can simply use that seed to seed your own CSPRNG.

There is really little need to do so, as the8472 already explained, but if you want to generate your own CSPRNG ([or DRBG as it is known to NIST](http://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/SpecialPublications/NIST.SP.800-90Ar1.pdf)) then nothing is stopping you - simply provide the seed in the constructor of your `SecureRandom` implementation.

The chance that you can generate better entropy yourself is minimal. You can use the standard [`System.nanoTime()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#nanoTime()) and *add* that to the internal state of the CSPRNG using the badly named `setSeed` method. I'd call one of the `nextXxx` methods before doing so though, otherwise you may *replace* the state instead of adding entropy to it.

---

Note that it is possible to extend `SecureRandom`; this is not the case for most of the other cryptography related classes. Implementing a CSPRNG is not of weak of heart; the chance that you will create a better CSPRNG as SHA1PRNG is minimal (the Apache implementation had some pretty horrible properties, to name just one attempt).