# How to collect entropy sources in JRE(Java Runtime Environment)?

Tags: java, random, seed

I wish to find entropy sources(noise source) in JRE. 
(Entropy source means a seed material(or Seed) of PRNG(Pseudo random number generator).)

However, I don't exactly know what is good entropy sources for the seed.

So I have difficulty finding proper entropy sources in JRE.

Would you tell me about this?

Comment: You could *potentially* read from a microphone **or** `/dev/urandom` **or** some other external source; it's unclear exactly what you're asking here.

Answer (score 1):

You can extract entropy from different sources within the JVM:

- The most obvious source is the clock

  ```
  System.currentTimeMillis();
  System.nanoTime();
  ```
- You can ask for the free memory, which changes quite often

  ```
  Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory()
  ```
- You can also use the internal hashCode of objects as entropy

  ```
  System.identityHashCode(someObject)
  new Object[0].hashCode()
  ```
- Going for heavier stuff, maybe the most comprehensive source of entropy are the [MXBeans](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/management/ManagementFactory.html), they have many properties which change quite unpredictably over time.

  ```
  ManagementFactory.getMemoryMXBean()
  ManagementFactory.getThreadMXBean()
  ...
  ```
- Finally, you can always generate [Random](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html) and [SecureRandom](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/SecureRandom.html) numbers or [random UUIDs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html#randomUUID--), for example

  ```
  new Random().nextLong()        
  new SecureRandom().nextLong()
  UUID.randomUUid()
  ```

By the way, somebody asked quite the same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42457032/how-to-get-entropy-from-jvm), with not much more success.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine the JVM as a sandbox.

When you are not allowed to leave the sandbox, your options are pretty much limited. Then you can do simple things, such as asking the user to do random typing on the keyboard, or you put up a panel and have him use the mouse to draw something.

But if your use case allows for making system calls, you can look into more advanced options based on the specifics of the operating system you are running on.

Answer (score 0):

You probably should use SecureRandom if you're not interested in reaching for the underling Operating System or other external to the JVM sources.

Here's the official answer from Oracle:

> A fast Random number designed for basic tasks where true randomness is
>   not the main goal. This is useful for things like which shade of color
>   to use, preventing overlap in force-directed layouts, or which picture
>   to show from a list after evaluating demographic information.
>
> High-concurrency programs may also use ThreadLocalRandom if they value
>   speed over true randomness. This is the same as above but will likely
>   give better performance if simultaneous threads generate pseudo-random
>   numbers at the same time.
>
> A slower but more random SecureRandom
>   designed for important tasks where the inability to predict numbers is
>   crucial to success. Examples include cases like gambling, scientific
>   sampling, or any cryptographic operations. Although slower than the
>   other two random number generators, its better randomness in many
>   applications.

Full post: https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/thats-so-securerandom